# How to add extent to OpenLayers map in AngularJS

Tags: openlayers, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and angular-openlayers-directives to make a simple map, now I saw this simple example online **[HERE](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/043-layers-bing-maps-example.html)**.

I just wanted to modify the code, to add an `extent` so that layers beyond a certain dimension would not be loaded, so my code looks as follows:

```
var coordinate1, coordinate2,
coordinate1 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6013, 12.9044]),
coordinate2 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6885, 12.9536]),
latlon = ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6244159, 12.9370699]);

app.controller('DemoController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        quebec: {
            lat: latlon[0],
            lon: latlon[1],
            zoom: 5
        },
        bing: {
        extent:[coordinate1[0], coordinate1[1], coordinate2[0], coordinate2[1]],
            source: {
                name: 'Bing Maps',
                type: 'BingMaps',
                key: 'Aj6XtE1Q1rIvehmjn2Rh1LR2qvMGZ-8vPS9Hn3jCeUiToM77JFnf-kFRzyMELDol',
                imagerySet: 'Road'
            }
        }
    });

} ]);
```

See how I am generating the coordinates:

```
var coordinate1, coordinate2,
coordinate1 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6013, 12.9044]),
coordinate2 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6885, 12.9536]),
latlon = ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6244159, 12.9370699]);
```

and using them in the following fashion :

```
quebec: {
     lat: latlon[0],
     lon: latlon[1],
     zoom: 5
   }
```

and also here:

```
extent:[coordinate1[0], coordinate1[1], coordinate2[0], coordinate2[1]]
```

Now this does't work, if I remove the `extent` parameter, I realize the map is somewhere in the Arabian sea, which is not the coordinates I have specified. So Where am I going wrong here and how do I specify extent using the angular-openlayers-directive?

Comment: After a bit of testing , i beleive the extent is being set correctly , so i believe , my coordinates are going wrong !! :( , i don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

The coordinates you supply are getting mixed up.  I can't decipher where you are trying to show. But when you initialise the coordinates using `ol.proj.fromLonLat` this function accepts and returns a coordinate in order xy eg lonlat as per the method signature, see here http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.1/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.fromLonLat

Change the variable `latlon` to `lonlat`

And change the point to the following, as at the moment the x and y are getting mixed up.

```
quebec: {
        lon: lonlat[0],
        lat: lonlat[1],
        zoom: 5
    },
```

But also ensure that the coordinates you're giving are in the order xy/lonlat.  I think that the extent is set correctly, if the coordinates are in xy/lonlat.

I don't know if this will fix your issue, but should make it easier to work out.

Comment: what is `lonlat` , there is nothing of that name in my code.

Comment: From you code `latlon = ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6244159, 12.9370699]);` I'm suggesting changing that variable `latlon` to `lonlat`, so that there's no confusion with the ordering of lon and lat.

Answer (score 0):

To add extent to OpenLayers map in AngularJS follow below steps. These steps fixed my issue.

1. Add `import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj'` lib in your component.ts file where logic is written.

[image]

2. Add `fromLonLat([long, lat])` under view object as shown below.

[image]